# How to hide the symbol number on PowerDesigner?

Tags: drawing, uml, sybase, diagram, powerdesigner

In Sybase PowerDesigner, when designing an UML diagram that takes 2 copies/instances of the same XXXX object (ie. objects), the application adds a number identifier like "XXXX : 2" to that symbol.
Is it possible to remove it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It does not seem to be directly doable.

However, (somewhat tested with 16.0), you can add an Extension to your model, define a computed attribute (type String) on your object type, returning the object name:

> %Get% = obj.name

and use `Tools > Display Preferences > xxx > Advanced` to modify the symbol contents, and use your computed attribute instead of `Name`...

Answer (score 1):

V 16.5

You can do that:

1. Select the Relationship
2. Right Click - `Format...`
3. Click on the `Content` tab
4. Go to the `Center` Section
5. Uncheck `Name`, keep `Stereotype` checked