# powerdesigner how to show table and field's code in diagram

Tags: c#, asp.net, uml, powerdesigner

I want powerdesign show table and field code(not noly their name) in diagram,how  to set it?
[image]

in this pic it only can display their name. code were hiden.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentionned in [an answoer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841561/how-to-hide-the-symbol-number-on-powerdesigner), you could use a Computed Attribute, containing the Name and Code, in your symbol instead of the usual Name/Code attribute...