# Customisation of PowerDesigner model

Tags: database, model, powerdesigner

I've got a DWH logical model in SAP PowerDesigner. How can I choose the properties to display on the diagram?

For example, instead of showing the Attribute's data type on the scheme, I would like to represent its description.

I've tried doing this:

***Right-click on the object > Format... > Content > Attributes***.

There you can choose between Stereotype, Identifier indicators, Data type, Domain or data type, Domain, Mandatory and either hide or show them.

However, each Attribute has custom Comment and Description and I can't select them there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even by going through Customize Content, `Tools > Display Preferences > Entity > Advanced`, it seems you can only display **single-line** attributes, which excludes Comment, Description, Annotation. Maybe because Attributes appear as a list on the Entity symbol, so the Attribute Description would be hard to fit in this list.

As [I suggested elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841561/how-to-hide-the-symbol-number-on-powerdesigner), you could try to use a Computed Extended Attribute.

Answer (score 0):

[Layout for Metaclass Attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pnkT.png)

On the diagram, right-click menu option 'Display Preferences', left panel navigate to metaclass 'Entity', tab 'Content'. Pick the button 'Advanced' in right bottom.

Built a layout by picking attributes and collections of the metaclass.

Choose fonts and colors on the Format Tab